# How to prove convergence of a sequence of binary numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra, automata, simple-functions, boolean-ring

I have a boolean expression with 4 inputs and 1 output, that when iterated onto itself(output->input(s)), the function converges to 1.
How do I go about proving the convergence of a sequence of binary numbers?

Ive been playing around with the idea of learning more about statistical analysis to find out if there are hints there, since I can generate a very big dataset of binary numbers by that expression.

Or should I learn more about binary trees? And try to solve it that way?

Just to give a simple example of what I mean:
a set of integers: {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}.
in binary:

```
1010
1001
1000
0111
0110
0101
0100
0011
0010
0001
```

at final step it produce 1. So by the dataset it is easy to see that. But how do one go around proving that by a formula like a boolean expression?

*I want to be able to understand proof-techniques for integers like binary 2-state boolean expressions rather than plain decimal numbers*

Thanks for your time

Comment: What do you mean "4 inputs and 1 output"? In your example with $1010, 1001,\ldots$, why is that the bottommost step is "final"? In what sense does that "converge"?

Comment: The convergence to 1 was a lousy example. I just would like to know how to prove some expression converges to a certain binary number. By 4 input 1 output i mean for example like an expression like: $(A | B & C | D) = X_out$

Comment: "It is difficult to achieve convergence of a CA towards a specific static pattern and a common solution is to use genetic algorithms and evolve a ruleset that describes cell behaviour." I read this from a paper, which explains approximately what I want to achieve. And I do have a ruleset which is a boolean expression. I do want to prove that the expression I have is converging. But dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

The "function" you use is $a_{n+1}= a_n- 1$. Given any positive initial number that gets **every** number less that the initial number so certainly 1.

Comment: I speculated $0000$ might be followed by $1111$, as if taken modulo $2^4$.

Comment: I want to know how to prove that by iterated function having only the boolean expression formula.